# Recieving fake WM_LBUTTONDOWN messages in a window

Tags: winapi, message, mouse

I have a `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` handler that basically does nothing, just changes some global variable. The problem is, my `wndProc` receives fake `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` messages. I receive exactly 4 fake messages before the window is displayed.

All of these messages have coordinates of the "press" equal to the size of my client area (so 1 pixel out of the actual clickable zone) and `wParam` is 0. No `WM_LBUTTONUP` is ever received after these fake "presses".

After the first genuine `WM_LBUTTONDOWN`, I receive another fake `WM_LBUTTONDOWN`, after which, I get the real `WM_LBUTTONUP`.

At all the next real mouse presses, I can't see any more fake ones.

I tested it in another program's window, and everything works as expected. So it's not related to any hardware mouse issues.

How can this be possible? I have no mouse hooks installed, I never post any messages myself in my code. I checked everything possible. It's just some kind of impossible magical stuff...

Comment: *"I tested it in another program's window, and everything works as expected."* - From that, it seems plausible that the issue is specific to your program. Please show a [mcve].

Comment: Perhaps missing `break` in `switch`.